jpegs which refuse to be moved or deleted
When I try to drag/drop file names TERMINAL refuses to accept them even sudo. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

What errors do you see in Terminal when this happens?

"Even sudo" is a nonsense statement.  Please show what command you are trying to DnD filenames to.

sudo rm and then dragdrop filename

There is no error message because - when dragging the file to terminal it is as if there is nothing there -terminal doesn't see it. Nothing drops where it is suppose to go.  It is invisible to terminal.  When you attempt, in finder, to delete or move it there is the annoying beep "can't do this".  Thanks for your replies. Pat
